# lapack dorgqr qr decomposition matrix $m\times n$ with $m<n$

Tags: lapack, matrix

I'd like to do a $A=QR$ decomposition of a matrix $A$, with $m\times n$. I use `dgeqrf_` (or `dgeqp3_`) to proceed to the first part of the decomposition. Then, I can easily compute the matrix $R$ by taking the upper diagonal part of the output matrix.

If $A$ is such that $m > n$, the Lapack subroutine `dorgqr_` create the correct $Q$ matrix.

But if $A$ is such that $m < n$, the same subroutine gives me an error :

```
** On entry to DORGQR parameter number  2 had an illegal value
```

I guess it's because $m<n$... should I use another routine for this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the input arguments for [dorgqr](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dorgqr.f). The second argument is the width of the orthogonal/unitary matrix which you would like to generate as the product of the Householder reflectors generated by [dgeqrf](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dgeqrf.f) or [dgeqp3](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dgeqp3.f). While both of these routines support the $m \le n$ case, you should recognize that, when $m \le n$, the QR decomposition implies a $Q$ which is $m \times m$ and an $R$ which is $m \times n$, and $Q$ is implicitly defined as the product of the $m$ Householder transformations implied by each of the first $m$ columns of the output of [dgeqrf](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dgeqrf.f)/[dgeqp3](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dgeqp3.f).

You should thus have the first, second, and third argument of [dorgqr](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dorgqr.f) each equal to $m$. My guess is that you used the width of $A$, $n$, for the second argument, which would be illegal.

Comment: thx, good guess, it is exactly the mistake i made...

Answer (score 2):

Usually people use the QR decomposition for tall/skinny matrices, as Jan pointed out. For short/fat matrices, the LQ decomposition is more appropriate. It is basically a QR on the transpose of the matrix, and you use routine `dgelqf`.

If you state what you intend to do with the factorization, we might be able to point out better and more specific solutions.

Comment: I have deleted my post...